Running the first Context program
After some effort I managed to install Context on my Windows 11 laptop. I am trying to compile the Doc01.tex program:
\setuppapersize[A6]
\starttext
\startsection[title={Testing ConTeXt}]
This is my first ConTeXt document.
\stopsection
\stoptext

and when compiling I get the following error message:
No test script block is provided. (Have you put the open curly brace on the next line?)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Context.ps1:49 char:37
+ ... ixture  = $(Throw "No test script block is provided. (Have you put th ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (No test script ...the next line?):String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : No test script block is provided. (Have you put the open curly brace on the next line?)

Please help to overcome this problem!

That error message does not look like anything I've seen with context. Are you sure that you have run context Doc01.tex? What output do you get if you do context --version?

how did you install context? most people simply install texlive or miktex tex distribution, although you can install a specific context distribution without latex from the contextgarden website.

You've got a PowerShell function called context that's running instead of the TeX program. Try running context.exe instead of just context.
